# Azure Profile.Model being spliced into array in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I can't seem to find anything on the web that would explain why Azure Profile.Model would be added to the array of sql servers i'm trying to retrieve using powershell azurerm resource commands. Stepping through the following code on debug shows that the array of sql servers being returned from my function only shows 4 elements in the resource group i've specified, all are sql servers retrieved with the following command.

```
$sqlServers = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName `
  $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers `
  -IsCollection -ApiVersion 2015-05-01-preview
```

The code above sits in a function to retrieve the servers for a given resource group. At the bottom of the function i simply `return $allServers`.

```
Function GetSharedServers {
    Param (
        [string]$subscriptionId
    )

    if($subscriptionId -eq "") {
        return @()
    }

    Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup

    $allServers = @()
    foreach($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
        $sqlServers = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers `
            -IsCollection -ApiVersion 2015-05-01-preview
        if ($sqlServers.count -gt 0) {
            $allServers += $sqlServers
        }
    }
    return $allServers
}
```

And the code calling this function

```
$sqlServers = GetSharedServers $subscriptionId
```

In GetSharedServers on Debug, the $allServers array only contains 4 elements, all of which are SQL Server Instances. As soon as I step out into the code calling that function the Profile.Model is added. So above, $allServers is Sql servers, and $sqlServers now has a Profile.Model spliced into the 0 element. The function below just loops through the $sqlServers array being returned from GetSharedServers, and this is where I have to start at 1.

```
Function SelectSharedInstance {
    Param (
        [array]$sqlServers,
        [string]$env
    )

    # Starting at 1 since for some reason azure account is passed as 0?
    for($i = 1; $i -le $sqlServers.length -1; $i++) {
        Write-Host $i ")" $sqlServers[$i].Name "`r"
    }
    $selectedServer = Read-Host -Prompt "Please select a $env shared sql server instance"
    return $selectedServer
}
```

As i said above, stepping through that function on debug in vscode shows the array being returned only contains the 4 servers on the resource group. However on the next debug step, when i return to the script calling that function, magically the array now has a new [0] element which is of type `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Model`.

This means that now to just list the `$allServers` returned i have to start at the [1] element as the array has been compromised with a profile element. Which is not a huge deal, just is not the desired outcome.

My question now being does anyone know why `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Model` would be maliciously spliced into my array using azure powershell? I've tried to Remove-AzureRmContext -DefaultProfile before returning the array to see if i could unset my context and hopefully not add it to the array, which did not help. I'm at a loss here as far as why that would just be added to my array.

Comment: Can you share the whole function with us?

Comment: @MartinBrandl I've updated with the code that calls the function as well as the next function that uses the returned servers array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either pipe the result of the `Set-AzureRmContext` to null or assign it to a variable. Otherwise the return value will be put to the pipeline and returned by your `GetSharedServers` function:

```
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId | Out-Null
```

Note that in PowerShell you don't need to use the `return` keyword to return something from a function, it is only used to exit a function.

Comment: that did the trick, thank you! I knew it was something about unsetting the context, just wasn't sure how to go about doing that. As far as the returns go, even thought they may not be required, they really just make me feel safe coming from other programming languages.